# How to get the items of previous transactions paypal omnipay

Tags: php, paypal, omnipay

I had a table with orders that were dropped accidentally, I am trying to recreate the orders but I can't see the items in Paypal. Any Ideas? Any help is really appreciated.

```
$second = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'quantity' => $order->secondary_quantity,
                'price' => $order->secondary_price,
            );
            $items->add($second);
```

Comment: Can't you check the paypal manually? I know it might sound tedious, but the issue sounds serious, so it might be the fastest way, and reconstruct the table off that.

Comment: I checked manually and there isn't any info there I tried the transaction search, brings back the addresses but not the items.

Comment: Hmmm... Try contact PayPal services. You should have info that would incline them to give the information that you are looking for. Worth a shot.